# Pandas divide multiple mutliindex columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

and I'd like to divide the `x` columns by the `y` columns, but at the moment I get the following result:

[image: result dataframe]

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

# create example dataframe
data = {'x': [2, 4, 6], 'y': [1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.concat([df, df*10], axis=1, keys=['apple', 'orange'])

# slice just x and y columns
x = df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'x')]
y = df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'y')]

# divide (this doesn't work)
result = x / y
```

Ideally I'd like to add the result back as a separate column:

[image]

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution working if same second level created by `rename`:

```
new = (x.rename(columns={'x':'x/y'}) / y.rename(columns={'y':'x/y'}) 
print (new)

  apple orange
    x/y    x/y
0   2.0    2.0
1   2.0    2.0
2   2.0    2.0
```

Or is possible use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) - be default is removed selected level, so divid working nice (because same columns in `x` and `y` `DataFrame`), so is necessary create second level by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
x = df.xs('x', axis=1, level=1)
y = df.xs('y', axis=1, level=1)
new = x / y
new.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([new.columns, ['x/y']])
print (new)
  apple orange
    x/y    x/y
0   2.0    2.0
1   2.0    2.0
2   2.0    2.0
```

And then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df, new], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1).reindex(['x','x/y','y'], axis=1, level=1)
print (df)
  apple         orange         
      x  x/y  y      x  x/y   y
0     2  2.0  1     20  2.0  10
1     4  2.0  2     40  2.0  20
2     6  2.0  3     60  2.0  30
```

Comment: `df.xs` is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!